# Inserting a row with running balance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert

I have a simple inventory DB with these columns

```
mat_id    material_name     supplier    stock_in      stock_bal    date
```

How can I add a row with the same material name and stock_in value will total to stock_bal?
Do I need to select?
my first input should be like:

```
mat_id    material_name     supplier    stock_in      stock_bal      date
1           paint            dummy         20            ?           feb13
```

the question mark should generate the stock_in total which is 20. And everytime I insert again with the same material name it should total the previous stock balance  and the new stock_in like:

```
mat_id    material_name     supplier    stock_in      stock_bal      date
1           paint            dummy         20            20           feb13
1           paint            dummy         10            30           feb13
```

Do i need to if/else my insert query?
pls help. im a just a beginner here

Comment: You shouldn't do this as a table in the database, you should calculate it as `select material_name, sum(stock_in) from inventory group by material_name`

Comment: I'm going to edit my post

Comment: Can i ask a fiddle sir? pls?

Comment: What are the results that you want?  I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: I updated it again sir.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve your issue is to calculate the records in your application level before inserting it on the database.

Comment: take a look at my post again sir. pls

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the cumulative sum is to use a subquery:

```
select i.*,
       (select sum(i2.stock_in)
        from inventory i2
        where i2.mat_id = i.mat_id and
              i2.date <= i.date
       ) as stock_bal
from inventory i;
```

This uses date for ordering the records.  Records with the same date will have the same `stock_bal` because the data has no other column to distinguish the order of things with the same date (such as an auto incremented/identity column).

Comment: i tried this sir but it doesn't total the stock_in.

Comment: What do you mean?  It should be producing the cumulative value when the dates are different.  What is it producing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you need, but i'll try to explain :
If in your table exemple mat_id 1 and 3 are exactly the same paint (same brand and EAN bar code), your table model is incorrect, it'd be better to make to distinct tables (product and supplier, a third one to reference which materials could be send by a supplier / which supplier could send a product and the delivery history.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `DELIVERY_HISTORY` (
  `dh_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `delivery_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `stock_in` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dh_id`),
  KEY `shm_id` (`shm_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MATERIAL` (
  `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `material_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock_bal` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`material_id`),
  KEY `material_name` (`material_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SUPPLIER` (
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `supplier_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`supplier_id`),
  KEY `supplier_name` (`supplier_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL` (
  `shm_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `supplier_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `material_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`shm_id`),
  KEY `supplier_id` (`supplier_id`,`material_id`),
  KEY `material_id` (`material_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `DELIVERY_HISTORY`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `DELIVERY_HISTORY_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`shm_id`) REFERENCES `SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL` (`shm_id`);

ALTER TABLE `SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`material_id`) REFERENCES `MATERIAL` (`material_id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`supplier_id`) REFERENCES `SUPPLIER` (`supplier_id`);
```

In this case you can create several materials and suppliers, reference which material is provided by which supplier or simply give the list of all products that a supplier can provide, an history of the suppliers delivery.

Now add the materials :

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`MATERIAL` (`material_id` , `material_name` , `stock_bal`) VALUES (NULL , 'paint', '0'), (NULL , 'bolt', '0');
```

Add the suppliers :

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`SUPPLIER` (`supplier_id` , `supplier_name`)
VALUES
(NULL , 'dummy'),
(NULL , 'test'),
(NULL , 'demo');
```

Add references materials / suppliers

```
INSERT INTO `SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL`
(`shm_id`, `supplier_id`, `material_id`)
 VALUES 
(NULL, 1, 1),
(NULL, 2, 2),
(NULL, 3, 1);
```

Show some utils queries :
List all materials and suppliers :

```
SELECT m.material_name, s.supplier_name
FROM MATERIAL m, SUPPLIER s, SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL shm
WHERE shm.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
AND shm.material_id = m.material_id
```

List all suppliers for a specific material :

```
SELECT m.material_name, s.supplier_name
FROM MATERIAL m, SUPPLIER s, SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL shm
WHERE shm.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
AND shm.material_id = m.material_id
AND m.material_id = 1
```

List all materials for a specific supplier :

```
SELECT m.material_name, s.supplier_name
FROM MATERIAL m, SUPPLIER s, SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL shm
WHERE shm.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
AND shm.material_id = m.material_id
AND s.supplier_id = 1
```

Show a product stock :

```
SELECT m.material_name, m.stock_bal
FROM MATERIAL m
WHERE m.material_id = 1
```

From here if you use PHP, I think you know the value of stock_in, supplier and material.

Find the ID of material/supplier in SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL (material_id = 1 : paint; supplier_id = 1 : dummy)

```
SELECT shm.shm_id
FROM MATERIAL m, SUPPLIER s, SUPPLIER_HAS_MATERIAL shm
WHERE shm.supplier_id = s.supplier_id
AND shm.material_id = m.material_id
AND m.material_id =1
AND s.supplier_id =1
```

In my case shm_id = 1. Now it's time to add a delivery (stock_in = 20) :

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`DELIVERY_HISTORY` (
`dh_id` , `shm_id` , `delivery_date` , `stock_in`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 20
)
```

Now UPDATE the material stock_bal with value of stock_in (20) for material paint (material_id = 1)

```
UPDATE MATERIAL
SET stock_bal = (stock_bal + 20)
WHERE material_id = 1
```

Note in PHP you can check the value of mysqli_insert_id function after INSERT. If value > 0 then INSERT was done correctly else you can code a fallback routine.

You can now check the value of your paint stock_bal.

Here are the 2 last INSERT and UPDATE to finish your test case, but don't forget to use the select before to understand how I get shm_id :

```
-- shm_id = 2 : material_id = 2 (bolt) / supplier_id = 2 (test)
-- Adding 10 bolt
INSERT INTO `test`.`DELIVERY_HISTORY` (
`dh_id` , `shm_id` , `delivery_date` , `stock_in`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 10
);
UPDATE MATERIAL
SET stock_bal = (stock_bal + 10)
WHERE material_id = 2;
-- CHECK YOUR MATERIAL stock_bal
-- shm_id = 3 : material_id = 1 (paint) / supplier_id = 3 (demo)
-- Adding 10 paint
INSERT INTO `test`.`DELIVERY_HISTORY` (
`dh_id` , `shm_id` , `delivery_date` , `stock_in`
)
VALUES (
NULL , 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 10
);
UPDATE MATERIAL
SET stock_bal = (stock_bal + 10)
WHERE material_id = 1;
-- CHECK YOUR MATERIAL stock_bal
```

I Hope this explanation will help you (if I've understood your problem correctly).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 'mat_id', 'material_name', 'supplier', 'stock_in',
       @running_bal := @running_bal + ('stock_in')  as 'stock_bal', date
FROM   YourtableName, (SELECT @running_bal := 0) tempName